# AdaptiveCardsJson - Click to call option without opening new URL

Tags: json, adaptive-cards

I've got a Json AdaptiveCard that presents information on employees in the business with their name, job title, phone number, email etc..

We've set it up to dial their telephone number on a click to call, but clicking the number opens up a new URL which we don't want. We want it as a background action.

How can we achieve this? Here's our code (Look at the section that has FaceSet, then a Telephone value, it's that value that creates the click to call:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
      "title": "Call",
      "url": "dial:{{Phone}}"
    }
  ],
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": "auto",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "Image",
              "url": "http://intranet.christiegroup.com/stafflisting/staff/{{Reference}}.jpg",
              "size": "medium",
              "style": "people"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": "stretch",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "{{FullName}}",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "wrap": true
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "spacing": "none",
              "text": "{{JobTitle}}",
              "isSubtle": true,
              "wrap": true
            },
            {
              "type": "FactSet",
              "facts": [
                {
                  "title": "Telephone:",
                  "value": "[{{Phone}}](dial:{{Phone}})"
                },
                {
                  "title": "Mobile:",
                  "value": "{{Mobile}}"
                },
                {
                  "title": "Email:",
                  "value": "{{Email}}"
                }

              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you rendering the cards yourself? Each SDK has a way of overriding the markdown rendering, so you could try that. Is `dial:` a custom scheme you own? Could you handle that at the OS level? Or use something like `tel:`?

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for responding it's good to see your name outside of the AdaptiveCard templates. I can't show you the code in comments but it's rendering in Teams (I'll update the main post shortly to show it). dial: is a handler that our phone system Horizon is looking for, it works it just opens in new URL rather than hidden